# Import A CSV file into Excel then save it in the correct format to import into SAGE One Accounting

Tags: excel, vba

Current The CSV file has columns A to H it is as follows:

[image]

Now I want to use VBA Excel and Active X Control Button to Import only Columns B, E,D, F in that order, I also want to concatenate E and D, it also needs to start importing from row 4 and needs to stop before the last row. It needs to add headers Date , Description and Amount. Now my big issue I am stuck with is, is the date column in the CSV file which is Column B, it is YYYYDDMM, I need it to be in dd/mm/yyyy otherwise it wont import into Sage One Accounting.

Here is my attempt:

```
Private Sub btnImportData_Click()
    Dim vR(), vDB
    Dim WbCSV As Workbook, Wb As Workbook
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, n As Integer
    Dim vFile As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set Ws = Wb.Sheets(2)

    'Select a text file through the file dialog.
    'Get the path and file name of the selected file to the variable.
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("ExcelFile *.txt,*.txt;*.csv", _
        Title:="Select CSV file", MultiSelect:=False)

    'If you don't select a file, exit sub.
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'The selected text file is imported into an Excel file. format:2 is csv, format:1 is tab
    Set WbCSV = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=vFile, Format:=2)

    'Bring all the contents of the sheet into an array.
    With WbCSV.Sheets(1)
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow < 4 Then Exit Sub ' If last row is less than 4, exit sub
        vDB = .Range("B4:H" & lastRow).Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            ' Adjust column numbers as needed
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 4, 1 To n)
            ' Convert yyyymmdd format to dd/mm/yyyy format
            vR(1, n) = ConvertDateFormat(vDB(i, 1))
            vR(2, n) = vDB(i, 5) ' Column E
            vR(3, n) = vDB(i, 6) ' Column F
            vR(4, n) = vDB(i, 4) ' Column D
        Next i
    End With

    'Close the text file
    WbCSV.Close (0)

    'The dynamic array is recorded in sheet2. Bring the row to the inverted state.
    With Ws
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("a1").Resize(n, 4).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
    End With

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Function ConvertDateFormat(dateValue As Variant) As Variant
    ' Convert yyyymmdd format to dd/mm/yyyy format
    If Len(dateValue) = 8 Then
        ConvertDateFormat = Format(DateSerial(Left(dateValue, 4), Mid(dateValue, 5, 2), Right(dateValue, 2)), "dd/mm/yyyy")
    Else
        ConvertDateFormat = dateValue ' Return original value if not in expected format
    End If
End Function
```

With this code I am importing the incorrect Columns and the date format is incorrect for example the format in the CSV is 20231002 which should convert to 02/10/2023 instead it converts it to 10/02/2023. Below is an Image of how I want it to be when I click on the import button

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of Excel sheets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table or this [Markdown Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Comment: Sorry about that I will use this vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format column A as dd/mm/yyyy before writing the array to the sheet.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnImportData_Click()
    Dim vFile, arIn, arOut()
    Dim wbCSV As Workbook
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, s As String
    Dim t0 As Single

    'Select a text file through the file dialog.
    'Get the path and file name of the selected file to the variable.
    vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("ExcelFile *.txt,*.txt;*.csv", _
        Title:="Select CSV file", MultiSelect:=False)

    'If you don't select a file, exit sub.
    If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    t0 = Timer

    'The selected text file is imported into an Excel file. format:2 is csv, format:1 is tab
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=vFile, Format:=2, ReadOnly:=True)

    'Bring all the contents of the sheet into an array
    'and close the text file
    With wbCSV.Sheets(1)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow < 4 Then Exit Sub ' If last row is less than 4, exit sub
        arIn = .Range("B4:H" & lastRow).Value
        
        wbCSV.Close
    End With
    
    'built output array from input array
    ReDim Preserve arOut(1 To UBound(arIn), 1 To 3)
    For i = 1 To UBound(arIn, 1)
        ' Adjust column numbers as needed
        s = Trim(arIn(i, 1))
        If Len(s) <> 8 Then
            MsgBox s & " date error", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
        arOut(i, 1) = DateSerial(Left(s, 4), Mid(s, 5, 2), Right(s, 2))
        arOut(i, 2) = arIn(i, 4) & " " & arIn(i, 5) ' Column E&F
        arOut(i, 3) = arIn(i, 6) ' Column G
    Next

    'write output array to sheet2
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
        .UsedRange.Clear
        .Range("A1:C1") = Array("Date", "Description", "Amount")
        .Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyy"
        .Range("B:B").NumberFormat = "@"
        .Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
        .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arOut), 3).Value = arOut
        .Columns("A:C").AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you I have adjusted it just a bit it was importing the Column G instead of D and it also imported the last row which had a 0, that's why I got the date error message.